# Invoking error handler due to Uncaught abort(59) at Error. How can I solve this?

Tags: unity-game-engine, auth0

So I am trying to create a Unity game for WebGl. In this game I need auth0 for the authentication part.

This is the code for the authentication part:

```
    var client = new AuthenticationApiClient(new System.Uri("..."));

    var authorizationUrl = client.BuildAuthorizationUrl()
        .WithResponseType(AuthorizationResponseType.IdToken, AuthorizationResponseType.Token)
        .WithClient("...")            
        .WithConnection("...")
        .WithAudience("...")
        .WithRedirectUrl("...")
        .Build();
    Application.OpenURL(authorizationUrl.AbsolutePath);
```

To make my page work I have a local server in XAMPP.
So the idea with this is that I need to click a button on the game redirect the page to an Auth0 authentication page and once I enter my username and password (for example gmail account) I go to the game again.

The problem is that whenever I click in this button, I get this error:
Invoking error handler due to

```
Uncaught abort(59) at Error
at jsStackTrace (htdocs.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:22295)
at stackTrace [Object.stackTrace] (htdocs.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:22466)
at Object.onAbort (http://localhost/Build/UnityLoader.js:4:11047)
at abort (htdocs.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:484763)
at wasm-function[56208]:3
at wasm-function[16961]:46
at wasm-function[43219]:1456
at wasm-function[56097]:16
at dynCall_iii [Object.dynCall_iii] (htdocs.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:459875)
at invoke_iii (htdocs.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:339724)
at wasm-function[43216]:388
at wasm-function[43215]:75
at wasm-function[43213]:99
at wasm-function[43212]:7
at wasm-function[43531]:69
at wasm-function[43530]:7
at wasm-function[28791]:330
at wasm-function[16681]:48
at wasm-function[23219]:1236
at wasm-function[16681]:48
at wasm-function[23267]:1090
at wasm-function[28454]:534
at wasm-function[48795]:330
at wasm-function[23210]:101
at wasm-function[22913]:152
at wasm-function[28604]:71
at wasm-function[28603]:128
at wasm-function[23091]:1169
at wasm-function[22398]:52
at wasm-function[22915]:11
at wasm-function[56135]:22
at dynCall_viiiii [Object.dynCall_viiiii]
```

And there is more from where this came from. I tried to solve this by searching for that error in google but failed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try to use a [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) logic for logging in (sending the form from within Unity) .. I guess the problem might be that what you are doing is open the page in a new tab/browser and break the Unity execution? (No WebGL expert though)

Comment: Thanks for the response. No, I never used that. I will do a research on that matter and see what happens. What I am trying to accomplish is something similar to what you said. In this new tab I need the auth0 login.